# Is there a module that provides payment processing but not a shopping cart?

Tags: 7, payment-gateways

I am building a website that allows users to "upgrade" their content. The user can choose a "premium" listing and once paid for their node will appear higher in a list of nodes.

I'm looking for a module that can do this, or a module that can at least provide the payment page so that I could customise the node editing process and direct them to this page, take their payment then update the node.

I know something like Ubercart can provide the payment processing but it has a very set payment checkout process that is more oriented to a shopping cart checkout process and would take a lot of time to customise for what I want.

Any recommendations on how to do this?

Im running Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried some of those ?

- [lm_paypal](http://drupal.org/project/lm_paypal):

  > This module provides an interface to PayPal using Instant Payment
  >   Notifications (IPN). It currently supports paid memberships
  >   (subscriptions), donations (tip jar) and paid adverts (classified
  >   ads).
- [Payment API](http://drupal.org/project/pay): this one need a specific module for the payment platform

  > This module can be used by other modules to collect and track payments. Through this API, any module can provide a payment form and payments can be handled and tracked centrally.
- [How to build a paid membership site with Drupal 7](http://www.moneyscripts.net/tutorials/membership-suite/how-build-paid-membership-site-drupal-7) (paid module)

Comment: Payment API I think is exactly what im looking for. cheers